# PANDAS select rows that contain most recent observation of pairing

Tags: python, pandas

The Problem:

I am looking to select only the most recent record of price within each pairing of uid and retailer.

The Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {"uid":{"0":"123","1":"345","2":"678","3":"123","4":"345","5":"123","6":"678","7":"369","8":"890","9":"678"},"retailer":{"0":"GUY","1":"GUY","2":"GUY","3":"GUY","4":"GUY","5":"GAL","6":"GUY","7":"GAL","8":"GAL","9":"GUY"},"upload date":{"0":"11/17/17","1":"11/17/17","2":"11/16/17","3":"11/16/17","4":"11/16/17","5":"11/17/17","6":"11/17/17","7":"11/17/17","8":"11/17/17","9":"11/15/17"},"price":{"0":12.00,"1":1.23, "2":34.00, "3":69.69, "4":13.72, "5":49.98, "6":98.02, "7":1.02,"8":98.23,"9":12.69}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df = df[['uid','retailer','upload date','price']]
df['upload date']=pd.to_datetime(df['upload date'])
```

Solution:

```
idx = df.groupby(['uid','retailer'])['upload date'].max().rename('upload date')
idx.reset_index(inplace=True)
solution = idx.merge(df, how='left', on=['uid','retailer','upload date'])
```

Question:

I would like to be able to leverage indices to get to my solution. Either, I'd like to be able to use join, or find the max date of each pairing with a function that retains the indices of the original data frame.

JOIN ERROR:

```
idx.set_index(['uid','retailer','upload date']).join(df, on=['uid','retailer','upload date'])
```

Returns:

```
ValueError: len(left_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "right"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,`idxmax`

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['uid','retailer'])['upload date'].idxmax()]
Out[168]: 
   uid retailer upload date  price
5  123      GAL  2017-11-17  49.98
0  123      GUY  2017-11-17  12.00
1  345      GUY  2017-11-17   1.23
7  369      GAL  2017-11-17   1.02
6  678      GUY  2017-11-17  98.02
8  890      GAL  2017-11-17  98.23
```

Or `reindex`

```
df.reindex(df.groupby(['uid','retailer'])['upload date'].idxmax().values)
```

---

If you want `join` the document stated *:Join columns with other DataFrame either on index **or** on a key column*

```
idx.set_index(['uid','retailer','upload date']).join(df.set_index(['uid','retailer','upload date']))
Out[175]: 
                          price
uid retailer upload date       
123 GAL      2017-11-17   49.98
    GUY      2017-11-17   12.00
345 GUY      2017-11-17    1.23
369 GAL      2017-11-17    1.02
678 GUY      2017-11-17   98.02
890 GAL      2017-11-17   98.23
```

To get your expected output you need adding `.reset_index()` at the end

Or doing something like

```
idx.join(df.set_index(['uid','retailer','upload date']),on=['uid','retailer','upload date'])
Out[177]: 
   uid retailer upload date  price
0  123      GAL  2017-11-17  49.98
1  123      GUY  2017-11-17  12.00
2  345      GUY  2017-11-17   1.23
3  369      GAL  2017-11-17   1.02
4  678      GUY  2017-11-17  98.02
5  890      GAL  2017-11-17  98.23
```

Comment: idx max returns the index of the value returned? i'll play around with it. Could you also show me how I could have used join? I don't understand why that doesn't work?

Comment: @YaleNewman you can join them by using index or column , add the solution for join, but I prefer `idxmax`,since it is straightforward

Comment: ahh ok this works cause they are unique in both dataframes but if we had two observations on the 16th, you couldn't set index to uid, retailer, upload date